# Liveness Probe gets timed

Tags: jenkins, kubernetes, google-compute-engine, google-kubernetes-engine

I'm using Jenkins and Kubernetes to perform this actions.

Since my loadBalancer needs a healthy pod I had to add the livenessProbe to my pod.

My configuration for the pod:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
labels:
  component: ci
spec:
  # Use service account that can deploy to all namespaces
  serviceAccountName: default
  # Use the persisnte volume
  containers:
  - name: gcloud
    image: gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud
    command:
    - cat
    tty: true
  - name: kubectl
    image: gcr.io/cloud-builders/kubectl
    command:
    - cat
    tty: true
  - name: liveness
    image: k8s.gcr.io/busybox
    args:
    - /bin/sh
    - -c
    - touch /tmp/healthy; sleep 30; rm -rf /tmp/healthy; sleep 600
    livenessProbe:
      exec:
        command:
        - cat
        - /tmp/healthy
      initialDelaySeconds: 5
      periodSeconds: 5
```

The issue that happens is when I want to deploy the code (CD over Jenkins) it comes to the touch

> /tmp/healthy;

command and it's timed out.

The error response I get looks like this:

```
java.io.IOException: Failed to execute shell script inside container [kubectl] of pod [wobbl-mobile-label-qcd6x-13mtj]. Timed out waiting for the container to become ready!
```

---

When I type **kubectl get events**
I get the following response:

```
Liveness probe failed: cat: can't open '/tmp/healthy': No such file or directory
```

Any hints on how to solve this?

I have read this [documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-liveness-readiness-probes/) for the liveness and I took the config for it from there.

Comment: why are you doing this any reason like creating and deleting again ? " - touch /tmp/healthy; sleep 30; rm -rf /tmp/healthy; sleep 600"

Comment: I'm testing out the pod health and I wanted to make it work over any way.The http livness check it's out of my scope for now so i tracked their example.

Comment: that example that you are referring is to make you understand the working of liveness probe. they have purposely used sleep 30 and removed the file . When liveness probe fails to find the tmp/healthy file it restarts the container and checks the liveness probe again.

Answer (score 3):

As can be seen from the link you are referring . The example is to help you understand the working of liveness probe. I the example below from this [link](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-liveness-readiness-probes/)

they have purposely removed /tmp/healthy file after

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  labels:
    test: liveness
  name: liveness-exec
spec:
  containers:
  - name: liveness
    image: k8s.gcr.io/busybox
    args:
    - /bin/sh
    - -c
    - touch /tmp/healthy; sleep 30; rm -rf /tmp/healthy; sleep 600
    livenessProbe:
      exec:
        command:
        - cat
        - /tmp/healthy
      initialDelaySeconds: 5
      periodSeconds: 5
```

what this does is it creates /tmp/healthy file when the container is created. After 5 seconds the liveness probe kicks in and checks for /tmp/healthy file , at this moment the container does have a /tmp/healthy file present . After 30 seconds it deletes the file and liveness probe fails to find the /tmp/healthy file and restarts the container. This process will continue to go on and liveness probe will fail the health check after every 30 seconds.

If you only add

- touch /tmp/healthy

The liveness probe should work well

Comment: If you could explain me how I can build the script to peform the health check i will accept your answer.Also thanks for your current answer it cleared some things out.

Comment: as i explained if you are just looking for a script that creates a /tmp/healthy file in container . you can keep it that way. containers:
  - name: liveness
    image: k8s.gcr.io/busybox
    args:
    - /bin/sh
    - -c
    - touch /tmp/healthy 

no need of adding content after that(; sleep 30; rm -rf /tmp/healthy; sleep 600). That should be enough.